# Azure Redis Cache cache.set() Not operable within Promise.then?

Tags: node.js, typescript, azure, redis, promise

This one has had me spinning my tires for about 2 days now, I'm ready to reach out for help :)

I have a google firebase functions app, running as a middle-ware to an angular SPA. Hoping to avoid some of the pay-by-use cost of Azure SQL, I wanted to implement a caching option for the most common queries.

I thought I knew redis, I've worked with it before. There's a simple enough example on the repo: https://www.npmjs.com/package//redis

Everything works fine, if it is top level.

But the way my application is built, i need the ability to set a cache value from within the .then of a Promise, and when I try to do that, all operation just stops, with no identifiable error logging, or even response from redis. Even in Azure insights, i'm not getting much feed-back, only that the 'set' operation isn't being counted in metrics.

So, just to clarify, this works:

```
// "cache", the object, set globally

export const testCache = functions.https.onRequest(
  async (req: any, res) => {

    await cache.connect();
    var redisKey = 'testing_global';

    var result = await cache.get(redisKey);

    await cache.set(redisKey, 'testing new class')

    console.log("\nDone");
    
    cache.disconnect();
    res.send('done');

  })
```

But, this does not:

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const cache = createClient({
            url: "rediss://" + process.env.REDIS_HOST_NAME + ":6380",
            password: process.env.REDIS_KEY,
        });

export const getValues = functions.https.onRequest(
  (req: any, response) => {

    cors(req, response, async () => {

      response.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);

      var searchText = req.body['search'];
      var offset = req.body['offset'];
      var fetch = req.body['fetch'];
      var x = req.body['x'];
      var y = req.body['y'];
      var districts = req.body['districtFilter'];
      var sort = req.body['sort'];

      if (offset) {
        if (!/^\d+$/.test(offset))
          throw new Error('bad number');
      } else {
        offset = 0;
      }

      if (fetch) {
        if (!/^\d+$/.test(fetch))
          throw new Error('bad number');
      } else {
        fetch = 200;
      }
                              
      if (x) {
        if (!/^-?\d+$/.test(x))
          throw new Error('bad number');
      } else {
        x = null;
      }

      if (y) {
        if (!/^-?\d+$/.test(y))
          throw new Error('bad number');
      } else {
        y = null;
      }

      if (districts && districts.length > 0) {
        districts = sanitizeStringArray(districts);
                                          
      } else {
        districts = null;
      }

      if (sort) {
        switch (sort) {
          case "scoreAsc":
          case "scoreDesc":
          case "priceAsc":
          case "priceDesc":
            break;

          default:
            sort = '';
        }
      }

      var redisKey = `get_values_${searchText}_${offset}_${fetch}_${x}_${y}_${districts}_${sort}`;
      var cacheResult: any = null;

      await cache.connect();
  
// because I want to end up in the 'else', for testing
      cacheResult = await cache.getFromCache('someOtherKey');
    
      if (null !== cacheResult) {

        response.send({
          "status": "success",
          "totalCount": cacheResult.totalCount,
          "data": cacheResult.result
        });

        cache.disconnect();

      } else {
        var connection = new Connection(sqlConfig);
        var totalCount: number = 0;
  
        connection.on('connect', function (err: any) {
          // If no error, then good to proceed.
          console.log("Connected");
  
          var sql = `EXEC SomeSPC;`;
  
          const sqlRequest = new Request(sql, function (err: any) {
            if (err) {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });
  
          const countRequest = new Request(
            `EXEC SomeOtherSPC;`
            , function (err: any) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err);
              }
            }
          )
  
          sqlRequest.connection = connection;
          countRequest.connection = connection;
  
          var result: any[] = [];
          sqlRequest.on('row', function (columns: any[]) {
  
            var rowResult: any = {};
            columns.forEach(function (column: any) {
  
              rowResult[column['metadata']['colName']] = column['value'];
  
            });
  
            result.push(rowResult);
          });
  
          sqlRequest.on("requestCompleted", function (rowCount: any, more: any) {
            console.log(rowCount + ' rows returned');
            connection.execSql(countRequest);
  
            countRequest.on('row', function (columns: any[]) {
                                  
              totalCount = columns[0]['value'];
                            
            });
  
            countRequest.on('requestCompleted', async function (rowCount: any, more: any) {

              connection.close();

              cacheResult = {
                totalCount: totalCount
                , result: result
              };

// ******************************************************************
// Does Not Work, Just Fails, Without Much to Go On
              await cache.set(redisKey, 'in Promise')

              response.send({
                "status": "success",
                "totalCount": totalCount,
                "data": result
              });

            })
          });
  
          connection.execSql(sqlRequest);
        });
  
        connection.on('infoMessage', infoError);
        connection.on('errorMessage', infoError);
        connection.on('end', end);
        connection.on('debug', debug);
  
        connection.connect();
  
        console.log("Reading rows from the Table...");
        }
    })
  }
)
```

There's **update- no longer ** a fair amount of psuedo-code here, so please **update- No Need to ** disregard any inconsistent lines. I went ahead and put in the full function, including all the fluff, since trimming the fat seems to make things difficult for others to understand what is being asked.

The sql stuff all works, if i take out the cache.set() everything is fine, but that line, in the result of the Promise, just fails, and I can't figure out why.

I've tried using cache locally and globally, extracting the cache operations to a function, and then to a separate class, and in all cases, i'm getting the same result.

Is there a known reason this wouldn't work?

Comment: I did resolve this issue, but unfortunately, it won't be much help in the future, since I didn't identify why this wasn't working. My fix was to pull the sql code, and all the .on events into a separate function, so I never leave this top-level-scope, in my main block. I'm still curious to identify what the issue was on this one, so I'll leave it open for an answer.

Comment: Did you try moving the event binding *before* running execSql(), as I have suggested?

Comment: I could be missing something,  but other than the necessary order of two separate queries, there is no event binding happening after execSql. I'm really not sure what you're asking.

Comment: As my original answer states: you are running `connection.execSql(countRequest);` before `countRequest.on('requestCompleted', ...)`: there may be a timing issue there and your even handler for _requestCompleted_ may never be called.

Comment: This may be, but as I can break within the 'requestCompleted' event, consistently. This is not the case, nor the focus of this question. Perhaps I got lucky in that this never became an issue, but with these being async this had not become an issue.
Irrespective, I don't expect that this has any bearing on why the redis.set fails.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand, given you didn't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), your code is binding to the `requestCompleted` event for the second request only *after* it runs `execSql()`: I would suggest moving the binding block *before* that, otherwise the event may be skipped.

Comment: Again, that was mostly psuedo-code, trying to only keep in the relevant parts. The SQL and events work as designed, the goal was to show the structure, which is an event, within an event, within an event (I may be wrong in assuming these are promises, since debugging has shown me there is no '.catch' supported here)
The most inner code is not getting skipped, in any case. I can break on this line. If there is syntax suggesting that in the example, that's a result of quick edits to get the 'point' across
I would hope this is evident, since it's explained, but I'll update